# Facebook open graph says access_token needed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to post the following the facebook Graph API explorer.

```
cody.short.94/notifications? access_token= {User Access Token} &template= this is a test &href= www.test.com
```

I want to be able to send the user a notification, but all attempts have failed. I'm currently getting this error:

```
{
   "error": {
       "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
       "type": "OAuthException", 
       "code": 15
   }
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing it, and I'm in need of some guidance. Any help would be appreciated. note: my app is currently marked for web so that it not the problem

Answer (score 3):

See, the error is quite self-explanatory :

> This method must be called with an app access_token

The **Notifications API** use the APP Access Token, not the user access token!

The App Access Token is: `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` or get directly from [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) for testing. (Make sure of the security of this token, this is very crucial and just like a password to your app)

Now test the query with Graph API Explorer , and remove the user token from the Access token field and replace it with the App Access Token

It will look something like this- 
[image]

Comment: It's still stating that it needs an access token.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I've shared the screenshot of the API explorer- how it should look like. Pls let me know if you still found any problem. Check can validate your app token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Also, pls note that you can not use `/me` here; since user token is not being used- instead use the `<user_id>`

Comment: Please be careful of your token. There's enough information left in that image to reconstruct it.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but its just a test app- let them reconstruct if they are so much interested. ;)

Comment: I'm doing exactly what is shown in the image, but it throws the exception. I have no idea what I could have wrong.

Comment: Well, in simple words- this is not possible. btw, did you checked the token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ ? Another thing, did you empty the access token field? Can you post your own screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you paste the app access token `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` on the top field that says Access Token[image]

Comment: in your image, you censored the app id, but still appears left center :)